# errors compiling lyx 2.1.2 document with Lyx 2.1.3

Tags: lyx

I have a Lyx document created with Lyx 2.1.2 on Windows 7 and everything compiles well. 
After upgrading to Lyx 2.1.3 the same document gives many errors when compiled.
I noticed that they are related to floating figures, for example uder view source I can see:

**

```
Figure \ref{fig:ErasOfComputingWant (2010)} adopted from \citep{Want2010}
illustrates conceptually three eras of modern computing. 
The Internet of Things initially thought of as connecting things to
the Internet for the purpose of remote monitoring and control it is
now moving into the concept of ubiquitous and pervasive computing
as it creates an intelligent, invisible network fabric that can be
sensed, controlled and programmed.
\begin{figure}[th]
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Images/0-ComputingEras}
\par\end{centering}
\protect\caption{Three eras of modern computing, source\citep{Want2010}{\footnotesize{}\label{fig:ErasOfComputingWant (2010)}}{\footnotesize \par}}
\end{figure}
```

**
The Lyx 2.1.3 gives corresponding errors:

```
*****Runaway argument?
{Three eras of modern computing, source\citep {Want2010}{\footnotesize \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \NR@gettitle was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.283 ...mputingWant (2010)}}{\footnotesize \par}}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...gWant (2010)}}{\footnotesize \par }}

l.283 ...mputingWant (2010)}}{\footnotesize \par}}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.*****
```

How to fix it?

Jan

Comment: This sounds like a bug. If you are able to create a minimal example in 2.1.2 that does note compile in 2.1.3 that you can upload that would be appreciated. If you can do that, please open a ticket at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: I did as you advised and will wait if any resolution will happen

Comment: OK, so I have the answer #9470:
 Reporter:  janeksz  |       Owner:  lasgouttes
     Type:  defect   |      Status:  fixed
 Priority:  normal   |   Milestone:  2.1.4
Component:  general  |     Version:  2.1.3
 Severity:  normal   |  Resolution:
 Keywords:           |
---------------------+-------------------------
Changes (by spitz):

 * status:  fixedinmaster => fixed

but what does it mean? Should I wait for a new release or what?

Comment: Yes, this means it will be fixed with LyX 2.1.4 and 2.2.0. Thanks for making the bug report.

Comment: You can answer and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, although my thoughts are that maybe the Lyx version 2.1.3 should be removed from the Lyx download section as problematic. At least I am not able to use it and I stay with 2.1.2